# How to modify the nodejs request default timeout time is unlimited?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm using a Node/express server. The default timeout of express is 120,000 ms, but it is not enough for me. When my response reaches 120,000 ms, the console will log POST /additem 200 120006ms and the page shows an error, so I want to set the timeout to a unlimited value. How would I do that?

Comment: Don't do that, you don't know what else in the network (e.g. proxies) will time you out. If you have a long-running task, don't try to do it in a single request-response cycle, see e.g. https://farazdagi.com/posts/2014-10-16-rest-long-running-jobs/

Comment: 0 and -1 is not working.. so please suggest something other solution.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right I have firebase request so need unlimited and I'm using nodejs api for it, so.